# Convert image format WBMP to BMP / PNG in C#

Tags: c#, image, png, converters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wbmp to Png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927391/how-to-convert-wbmp-to-png)

I am trying to figure out how to convert WBMP image format (wireless application protocol bit format) to png / bmp in C#! I have tried classes like Image, ImageConverter, Bitmap, BitmapSource and even directly streams and byte arrays but not successful yet. I can read the image through BinaryReader / Stream class as byte array where the contents are just numbers in the range of 0 - 255. But I don't know how to convert those to BMP pixels? I don't have image size as well with me. Otherwise I could have ran a loop and put the colours manually in that range.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19779/Converting-a-BMP-picture-to-WBMP-format

Comment: How can a question be a duplicate of a question asked after it?

Comment: @Kendall Frey - Lol that's funny ! No idea how can that happen !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the .NET does not support this conversion. However,  If you need advanced features or additional formats not supported by .NET itself, you'll need a third party library such as this:
http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats/image-formats.htm

Comment: Thanks. There is an algorithm to do it and I am using it now.

Comment: @VVV: Did you solve you problem by using this answer? If not, then you should not mark this answer as accepted, but post your own answer or pointer. Rememeber that the purpose of this site is to build a knowledge base so to help other people who face the same problem.

Comment: Yes there is an algorithm to convert it. I used that algorithm. vern.crider is correct. .NET doesn't support this conversion directly.